# Area of shaded region in a square

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, area, locus

[image: question]

***My approach***

The area of shaded region = 8×the area of [image: triangular figure]

*Given that the points of the shaded region are closer to the center than the boundary of the square.*

**Let's talk about the boundary of the shaded region**

The boundary of the shaded region therefore must be the locus of all the points whose distance from the center of the square = distance from the boundary.

**Let's find the locus of the boundary of the shaded region**

***From the second figure***
${\sqrt {h^2+k^2} } = {\sqrt {(h-h)^2 + (k-{a\over 2})^2 }}$

This simplifies to be:

$k = {a^2 - 4h^2\over 4a}$

$y = {a^2 - 4x^2\over 4a}$

*Also the curve intersects the line( the hypotenuse of the triangle) y= x*

For point of intersection :

$ {a^2 - 4x^2\over 4a} = x $

$4x^2 +4ax - a^2 = 0$
$x = {-4a ± \sqrt{16a^2 - 4×4×(-a^2)}\over 8}$
$x = a{(\sqrt{2} ± 1)\over 2}$

Solution 1: $x = a{(\sqrt{2} + 1)\over 2}$

Solution 2: $x = a{(\sqrt{2} - 1)\over 2}$

Solution 1 can be discarded as $ x = a{(\sqrt{2} + 1)\over 2} ≈ 1.207106 a > {a\over 2} $

Solution 2: $ a{(\sqrt{2} - 1)\over 2} ≈ 0.2071 a < {a\over 2} $

**from 0 to**  $a{(\sqrt{2} - 1)\over 2}$ :
The curve (boundary of shaded region)  lies above the line $ y=x$

so $dA = ({a^2\over 4a} - {4x^2\over 4a} - x)dx $

$dA = ({a\over 4} - {x^2\over a} - x)dx $

$\int_{0}^{A} dA = \int_{0}^{a{(\sqrt{2} - 1)\over 2}} ({a^2\over 4a} - {4x^2\over 4a} - x)dx $

A = $({a\over 4}x - {x^3\over 3a} - {x^2\over 2})]_{0}^{{a{(\sqrt{2} - 1)\over 2}}}$

$ A = {a^2\over 8}(\sqrt{2}-1) - {a^2\over 24}(\sqrt{2}-1)^3 - {a^2\over 8}
(\sqrt{2}-1)^2 $

$ = {a^2\over 8}(\sqrt{2}-1) \Biggl( 1 - {(\sqrt{2}-1)^2\over 3} - (\sqrt{2} -1)\Biggr)$

**This simplifies to be equal to**
${a^2\over 8}(\sqrt{2}-1)({3+5\sqrt{2}\over 3})$

$= {(7- 2\sqrt{2})\over 8×3}a^2$

Area of shaded figure = 8A

$A_{total}$ = ${(7- 2\sqrt{2})\over 3}a^2$

**But the answer is :**

${4\sqrt{2}-5\over 3}a^2 $

I don't know where I got it wrong, and also I have re calculated this and the result is same.

**Did I miss something important or calculated wrongly**

***Any help of hint or suggestion or worked out solution would be appreciated.***

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for providing worked out solutions and also pointing out the mistake that I had made. The mistake was in calculating A. It was a calculation mistake. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$   1 - {(\sqrt{2}-1)^2\over 3} - (\sqrt{2} -1)= \frac{3-\sqrt2}3
$$
not ${3+5\sqrt{2}\over 3}$.

Comment: Yeah!  I miscalculated it.

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates

$(x, y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$

In the range of $ 0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ we want

$ r \le \left( \dfrac{a}{2} - r \cos \theta \right ) $

Hence,

$ r \le \dfrac{ a } { 2 (1 + \cos \theta ) }  $

The area enclosed by this polar curve

$ r(\theta) = \dfrac{ a } { 2 (1 + \cos \theta ) } =\dfrac{a}{4 \cos^2(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) } $ is given by

$A = \dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int_0^\dfrac{\pi}{4} r^2(\theta) \text{d} \theta = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\dfrac{\pi}{4} \dfrac{a^2}{16 \cos^4 (\dfrac{\theta}{2})} \text{d} \theta = \dfrac{a^2}{32} \int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}} \sec^4(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) \text{d} \theta $

Now, let $ u = \dfrac{\theta}{2} $ then

$A = \dfrac{a^2}{16} \displaystyle \int_0^\dfrac{\pi}{8} \sec^4(u) du $

And since $\sec^2(u) = \tan^2(u) + 1 $, the above becomes

$A = \dfrac{a^2}{16} \displaystyle \int_0^\dfrac{\pi}{8} (\tan^2(u) + 1) \sec^2(u) du $

And this reduces to

$A = \dfrac{a^2}{16} ( \dfrac{t^3}{3} + t ) $

where $t = \tan(\dfrac{\pi}{8} ) = \dfrac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + 1} = \dfrac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{2} + 1 } = 
\sqrt{2} - 1 $

Therefore,

$A = \dfrac{a^2}{48} ( 2 \sqrt{2} - 3(2) + 3 \sqrt{2} - 1 + 3 \sqrt{2} - 3 ) = \dfrac{a^2}{24} (4 \sqrt{2} - 5) $

And since there is $8$ of these areas in the square, then the answer is

$ \text{Area} = 8 A = \dfrac{a^2}{3} ( 4 \sqrt{2} - 5) $

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{\frac a2(\sqrt 2 -1)}(\frac a4-\frac{x^2}a-x)dx=\frac{ax}4-\frac{x^3}{3a}-\frac {x^2}2\bigg|_0^{\frac a2(\sqrt 2 -1)}\\=a^2\left(\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{8}-\frac{(\sqrt 2-1)^3}{24}-\frac{(\sqrt 2-1)^2}8\right)\\=\frac{a^2}{24}(3\sqrt2-3-2\sqrt2+6-3\sqrt 2+1-3(2+1-2\sqrt 2))\\=\frac{a^2}{24}(4\sqrt 2-5)$$

Your error is when you did the simplification and obtained $3+5\sqrt 2$. That should be $3-\sqrt 2$. So $$\frac{a^2}8(\sqrt 2-1)\frac{3-\sqrt 2}3=\frac{a^2}{24}(\sqrt 2(3+1)-3-2)$$

Comment: Yes. I got it. I miscalculated that while multiplying with '-' sign

Answer (score 1):

The problem was here
A = ${a^2\over 8}(\sqrt{2}-1) \Biggl( 1 - {(\sqrt{2}-1)^2\over 3} - (\sqrt{2} -1)\Biggr)$

This equals to $a^2(\sqrt{2} -1){(3-\sqrt{2})\over 8×3}$

∴ $A_{total}$ = $8A = a^2{(4\sqrt{2}-5)\over 3}$

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for providing different ways of solution and mistakes in my question