# Finding the area of the region of a square consisting of all points closer to the center than the boundary

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, summation, area

[image]

> The shaded region inside the square of side a shown in the figure consists of all points that are closer to the center of the square than to its boundary. Find the area of
> this region

I was trying:
we want the sum of the areas of 8 triangles with base $(a-x)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and height $(a-x)$

$$8(\frac{1}{2}(a-x)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(a-x))$$
$$8(\frac{a^2\sqrt{2}-2ax-2x^2}{4})$$

but this approach fails because I have to express in terms of a

Hint: answer = $0.2189a^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area of shaded region in a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4385102/area-of-shaded-region-in-a-square)  Even the diagram you included in your question is the same one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to divide the shape into eight, as you've done. Let's look at the second octant (where $y>x>0$).

The shaded region is bounded by a curve. Points on this curve are the same distance from the origin and from the nearest side of the square (and for the second octant, this is the side where $y=\frac{a}{2}$).

In other words, a point $(x,y)$ on this part of the curve satisfies
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{a}{2}-y$$

Squaring,
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}{4}-ay+y^2$$

And so
$$y=\frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{a^2}{4}-x^2\right)$$

This meets the line $y=x$ when
$$x=\frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{a^2}{4}-x^2\right)$$

a quadratic with positive root $x=\frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt2-1\right)$.

The area of the triangle-like section in the second octant is then
$$A=\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt2-1\right)} \frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{a^2}{4}-x^2\right)-x dx$$

This evaluates to $A=\frac{a^2}{24}\left(4\sqrt2-5\right)$. This is an eighth of the total shaded area, which is
$$8A=\frac{a^2}{3}\left(4\sqrt2-5\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, I misread the diagram! Edited.

Comment: >"and for the second octant, this is the side where y=a/2"
can you elaborate on that one

Comment: You usually count octants, quadrants etc anticlockwise from the positive x-axis, so the second octant is the one between due north and northeast. The nearest side of the square to the second octant is the topmost one in your diagram, which is part of the line with equation $y=\frac{a}{2}$. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Dont see how the distance from the curve to the origin is the same as a/2-y

Comment: Points inside the region are nearer the centre, points outside the region are nearer the nearest side of the square, so points on the boundary of the region are equidistant from the centre and the side.

Comment: now is clear thanks

Answer (score 6):

I wondered whether you have noticed an elementary geometric property of a parabola. You can regard the center of this square as the focus, and the side as the directrix. Then you only need to calculate an easy integral.

Comment: can you set up the integral to see if I can understand better?

Comment: Imagine a parabola $x^2=ay/2$ and the Integral should be $\int_{(-2+\sqrt{2})a}^{0}x+a/2-{2x^2}/a dx$. And the answer should be 8 times the value of the integral.

Comment: I don't understand the limits of integration

Comment: You can try to parametrize the bottom left 1/8 curved triangle.